# C++11 std::thread std::move complaining attempt to use a deleted function

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am learning C++11 thread and tried to write a thread changing the shared memory. I used `std::ref` and `std::move` respectively. I ran the code using: `g++ eg3.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread`. However I found `std::move` does not work on my mac. I got error like this:

```
In file included from eg3.cpp:1: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:337:5: error: 
      attempt to use a deleted function
    __invoke(_VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<0>(__t)), _VSTD::move(_VSTD::get<_Indices>(__t))...);
    ^
...
```

My code is as follows:

```
#include<thread>
#include<iostream>
#include<mutex>
#include<condition_variable>
#include<string>
#include<functional>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  string s = "Hello!";
  cout << "Main before: " << s << endl;
  // thread t([](string& s){cout << s << endl; s = "Ni hao!";}, ref(s)); //// This works!
  // thread t([](string& s){cout << s << endl; s = "Ni hao!";}, move(s)); //// This does not work
  t.join();
  cout << "Main after: " << s << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't comment code just to remove compile error. Your question is about the compile error. So don't comment it. Plus, there is no color with comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to make the lambda takes `string` (by value) or `string const &` (by constant reference) or `string &&` (rvalue reference) to support move. In this case, because you are modifying `s`, and you can't use `string const &`.

```
thread t([](string && s){cout << s << endl; s = "Ni hao!";}, move(s));
```

---

It failed because you can't pass rvalue reference (`string &&`) to a function/lambda that takes lvalue reference (`string &`).

A simplified example is

```
void test(std::string &) {}
void test2(std::string &&) {}
void test3(std::string const&) {}
void test4(std::string) {}

int main(){
  std::string s;
  test(std::move(s)); // fail
  test2(std::move(s)); // ok
  test3(std::move(s)); // ok
  test4(std::move(s)); // ok
}
```

Comment: So if I want to change the shared value, like `s` in the code, I can only use `std::ref`?

Comment: When I tried to use `thread t([](string const& s){cout << s << endl; s = "Ni hao!";}, move(s));`, I got the following error: `eg3.cpp:39:54: error: no viable overloaded '='
  thread t([](string const & s){cout << s << endl; s = "Ni hao!";}, move(s));`

Comment: Sorry I should have some more testing before post the answer. See my edit. Also `move` is not intend for shared resource anyway. You have to use `std::ref` for that. But be careful with any shared resources between threads that you may need lock/mutex to protect them before accessing them.